# Set initial state as input on pins using FTDI device FT4232H

Tags: ftdi

I am using a USB device from FTDI called FT4232H and I want to write on the EEPROM to make sure that some pins are set to inputs at start. I am using the D2XX drivers (pdf [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer%27s_Guide%28FT_000071%29.pdf)). Here I found at page 106 that there is a struct called FT_EEPROM_4232H. Could this be something to use to make sure the pins are set to inputs at the beginning or is this totaly wrong? There are four UCHAR variables called A-, B-, C- and DDriverType. Does anyone know what these should be used for?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is 3 months old now but I believe pins on the FTx232H series of chips only get set as GPIO once the MPSSE command `SetOutput` is issued.

The EEPROM configuration is used to define things like drive strength, slew rate and whether the pin is a schmitt input and what each of the 4 ports are set up to be (async FIFO akin to FT245 series, serial port (FT232), etc).

If anyone else can disprove this, I would be interested to know also!

Answer (score 0):

I just plugged my FT232H board in my PC and ran FTDI FT_Prog, it does not appears you can control the GPIO mode input/output at start time. There is nothing in the FTDI FT_Prog UI that allow to set a mode for GPIO pins and set them as input.

I did set programmatically my FT232H board as an SPI device with 8 GPIOS
but this was done after the chip was started.

[A video experimenting with the FT232H](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i8_EFs_j0I)

I also once asked FTDI support a similar question for the FT232RL which is as default a UART and I asked if there was a way to configure the chip to start in Synchronous bit banging mode and set the GPIOs as OUTPUT. The answer was no.

The FT232RL will always start as a UART and then by software I can activate Synchronous bit banging mode, and set the mode of my GPIO.

I suppose it is the same for the FT232H, FT2232H and FT4232H.